# How to check if numbers 0 to 9 have appeared atleast once in a stream of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

There is a stream of incoming numbers (in Base 10, could be any number having 'n' digits, say the stream could be 123, 8, 670, 4835134, 50243)

I have to check if all the digits 0 to 9 have appeared after reading the entire stream.

Ex. if stream is `123, 8, 670, 48351934, 50243,` then the answer is "TRUE" (from 0 till 9, a number has appeared at least once)

if the stream is `123, 8, 670, 4835134,  50243,` then the answer is "FALSE" because 9 did not appear in any of the numbers in the stream

Fix - 1
I thought I can take Can take OR from 0 till 9 and have it (allORresult)
Calucatate OR of all the numbers in the stream (streamORresult)
If the set bits of allORresult and streamORresult are similar, then we can conclude all the numbers,0 to 9 have appeared atleast once in the numbers of the stream.

Fix - 2
Take the naive approach! Decompose the number starting from ones digit (%10 then /10) and set a flag for each digit. If all the digits are encountered, then return TRUE

Comment: Forget about parsing the integers. Read the entire file, check every character, and set a flag for each digit 0-9 encountered. At the end of the file check if all ten flags are set. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Convert numbers into strings, merge them, split into characters, create `std::set` of it and check whether it's length is equal to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing a function that may come in handy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool findAllDigits(istream & i){
    vector<int> digits(0);
    int tmp; char c; bool found;

    while(i >> c){//read one char
        if(isdigit(c)){//check if it is a number
            tmp = c - '0';//convert char to int
            found = false;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < digits.size(); ++i){
                if(tmp == digits[i]){
                    found = true; break;
                }
            }
            if(!found){//if this number wasn't in the vector yet
                digits.push_back(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    return digits.size() == 10;//return true if all the digits are in the stream
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/WMlJdC)

### More compact function that uses stl:

```
#include <algorithm>
bool findAllDigits(istream & i){
    vector<char> digits(0); char c;

    while(i >> c)//read one char
        if(isdigit(c) && find(digits.begin(), digits.end(), c)==digits.end())//check if it is a number and not in the vector
            digits.push_back(c);

    return digits.size() == 10;//return true if all the digits are in the stream
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/X6T7FS)

Comment: This is really nice. You have captured the fact the input is from the stream! Also, this is a naive approach M.M, can we do better here?

Comment: @PrasathGovind if you want something more compact check the second option

Answer (score 1):

The bit manipulation will not help you for this problem:

```
decimal      binary          
  123       0111 1011               
    2       0000 0010
   OR       0111 1011
```

You have either to convert the number to strings (or keep them as such) and process the characters that represent the digits, or you have to iterate using `%10` to get the last digit and use `/10` to process the next digit.

I leave you finish your exercise with this hint on your own.

Comment: Christophe... Thanks for the finding that BIT manipulation will not work. FYI, I already thought about %10 and /10 approach. I did not mention this in my question.

Answer (score 1):

you can scan the entire stream and use flags for each number form 0-9
http://ideone.com/yJ13SM

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char ch;
int flags[10];
do{
    ch=getchar();
    cout<<ch;
    if(ch>='0' && ch<='9')
        flags[ch-'0'] = 1;
}while(ch!='\n'); // some condition to stop scanning further
int flag = 0;
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
    if(!flags[i])
        flag++;
if(flag)
    cout<<"some digit was missing";
else
    cout<<"good coverage";
return 0;
}
```